# mongodb database return from callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have this code

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb'),  assert = require('assert');

var Db = mongodb.Db;

var db = new Db('local', new Server('localhost', 27017);

db.open(functioin(err, db){
    if(err) throw err;
    var adminDb = db.admin();
    adminDb.listDatabases(function(err, dbs){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(dbs);
    });
});
```

I want to export the dbs variable from the callback of the `listDatabases` function.
Is there any way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys. It finally worked for me with this code.

```
var db = new Db('test', new Server('localhost', 27017));
// Establish connection to db
db.open(function(err, db) {

  // Use the admin database for the operation
  var adminDb = db.admin();

  // List all the available databases
  adminDb.listDatabases(function(err, dbs) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    assert.ok(dbs.databases.length > 0);

    db.close();
  });
});
```